# configure custom storing paths for elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i am a beginner with elasticsearch and i was looking for someway to change the configuration with which it stores indicies's data .

i am storing large files of different formats which come on daily basis to my system and i dont want to have 2 copies of the data , the original file and the file after it has been inserted in elasticsearch.

so what i have done so far is make a python script to use Apache Tika parsing library and the elasticsearch api on python to parse file and extract the contents,metadata etc. and store those inside elasticsearch. now, what i would like to do is create a custom storage pathing instead of the way elasticsearch saves the data of the nodes/indicies/foo to become for example -> nodes/index/date-document-added/document-extention/documents-of-same-extention

is this in anyway possible ?

Comment: It's not possible